# How to create Service Reports on the Work Orders but not on Service Appointments on FSL mobile app

Tags: field-service-lightning

When ever I create a Service Report on the WO in the FSL mobile app, its getting created on the Service Appointment related list but on the WO. Our requirement is to create it on the WO. I tried the standard Create Service Request button and also tried through a flow with an app extension (Scoped to WorkOrder) but none of them generates a Service report on the Work Order. Any suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

here is an idea for this problem. It is related mainly to generation of report from FSL mobile app:

https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000E8WsQAK

Unfortunately, there does not seem to be workaround for it.

Answer (score 0):

If You place Service Report in the related list of "Service Appointment" layout - "Generate Service Report" button will appear on Service Appointment.

Note:- If Service Report button is in Service Appointment, the generated PDF will be related to SA, if it is WO - the generated report will be related to WO